# Using paypal on custom website and accept credit / debit Card

Tags: php, paypal

I have an issue right now that is killing me, I have implemented several payment options but never used paypal, I don't know why is it so complicated.

The website already exists and wasn't developed by myself.

I don't know the ammount of the order it is dynamic, so the "create payment buttons" on the paypal website doesn't work for me, at this point i developed a solution using

[PayPal developers](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/web/web-checkout/)

But it turns out that i only have the option to pay with a PayPal account or register a PayPal account, I do not want to force customers to do this, it has no sense. is there any relatively easy solution out there using the same PayPal API?

**EDIT**

The whole site code is in PHP so i need the solution in this language

Comment: you account type has to be  Premier or Business to accept credit cards directly. If you are serous about taking credit cards, there are much better gateways than pay pal.

Comment: agree with Dagon, much much better gateways try Worldpay and for paypal you need business account or Paypal Pro i think, so you can take payments on site without asking customer to login.

Comment: @Dagon That's the issue, my Customer wants paypal. otherwise i could use a different solution that's the problem, the owner account is a business one, but i cannot make it work with direct payment, always shows the same "PayPal" option

Comment: @DannyG, then you should accept the answer, if you check the Website Payment Pro WPP, its exactly what you need. Paypal Business account will always take you to paypal payment page. you need Payment Pro account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have mentioned that you are aware of one payment method i.e. Express Checkout ( in which user needs to have a valid Paypal account) so the other method which I think you need is the Direct Payment (i.e. a user can pay with credit cards directly without any Paypal account) [API](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_dcc_hub-outside).

For this direct payment api you need to enable Website Payment Pro WPP , [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-pro/integration-guide/WPWebsitePaymentsPro/)  you can get info about WPP.